# как поместить выполнение данной функции в отдельный поток при её вызове c#

Tags: c#, многопоточность

```
      public static  string GetLocation(string ipOrHost)
    {
        string locationResponse;
        string Query = @"https://freegeoip.net/xml/" + ipOrHost;
        try
        {
            locationResponse = new WebClient().DownloadString(Query);
        }
        catch (WebException)
        {

              _lastIp.Value = "Invalid IP or Host";
            return _lastIp.Value;
        }

        var responseXml = XDocument.Parse(locationResponse)
            .Element("Response");
        _lastIp.Value = responseXml.Element("City").Value + "," + responseXml.Element("CountryName").Value;
        return _lastIp.Value;

    }
```

Comment: Допустим, сделали в отдельном потоке, а дальше что? Т.е. надо учитывать ситуацию "поток отработал" и "поток не отработал". У вас в коде этого не видно. Если просто в отдельном потоке вычислить - потом ждать результата - то результат не будет отличатся от вашего.

Comment: вот http://www.cyberforum.ru/csharp-net/thread325254.html

Answer (score 2):

Вам придётся выучить async/await, и вызывать функцию асинхронно.

Получится что-то такое:

```
public static Task<string> GetLocationAsync(string ipOrHost)
{
    string locationResponse;
    string Query = @"https://freegeoip.net/xml/" + ipOrHost;
    try
    {
        using (var client = new WebClient())
            locationResponse = await client.DownloadStringTaskAsync(Query);
    }
    catch (WebException)
    {
        return "Invalid IP or Host";
    }

    return await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        var responseXml = XDocument.Parse(locationResponse).Element("Response");
        return responseXml.Element("City").Value + "," +
               responseXml.Element("CountryName").Value;
    }
}
```

«Общение» с `_lastIp` лучше вести в точке, где данная функция вызывается.

Comment: Спасибо за советы=)

Comment: @ВладРоменский: Пожалуйста!

Comment: @PavelMayorov: Я правильно помню, что `WebClient` лучше не пересоздавать каждый раз?

Comment: @VladD неправильно. Это довольно тонкая обертка вокруг WebRequest, который и вовсе одноразовый. У WebClient даже Dispose пустой (достался в наследство от Component)

Comment: @PavelMayorov: Ага, понял, спасибо! С чем-то другим перепутал. Но `Dispose` лучше всё же вызвать для порядка.

Answer (score 2):

Для запуска функции в отдельном потоке можно использовать [Task.Run](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/hh195051(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
Task.Run(() => GetLocation("111.111.111.111"));
```

Не забываем подключить

```
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
```

Есть и другие варианты запуска. Подробнее можно почитать [тут](https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/12.1.php).